# Tensorflow RNN: input of two different types

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to provide input with 2 types to my LSTM RNN Cells. My input is made up of list of integers (i.e. `[5,2,3,4,6,1,0, ...]` ).

However, each integer is categorized into 2 different groups, so I want to mark each integer, in a way like `[[5,True],[2,False], [3,False], [4,True], ... ]`.

I have seen cases where input is made up of same type of constants, with input dimension of 2 or above. But I'm not sure whether 2 different types can make 1 unit of input, like `[5,True]`. If this is not possible, I am thinking about substituting True into integer 2, and False into integer 1, so like `[[5,2], [2,1], ...]`, where input dimension is 2 (not sure this is good way to mark).

What would be a good way to mark each integer so that each belong to different group?

Comment: No, you cannot have a tensor with mixed data types. You can either, as you suggest, use an integer value to represent the boolean or have a separate tensor with the same shape but boolean data type.

Comment: In what way should I feed two separate tensors with same shape but with different data types to my LSTM Cell?

Comment: The thing is, LSTM (or any other RNN cell, or neural network layers in general) do not work with Boolean values, or even integers, just with float. I mean, looking at [how LSTMs actually work](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), you can see the operations are not defined for Booleans (unless you convert them to 1.0 and 0.0). [As Bily suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45439871/1782792), you can make a custom cell type, but you first need to decide _what_ to do with the Boolean values. If you want to use regular LSTMs, you need to use floats.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I now know that LSTM only works with float. I will read colah's blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow supports nested tuple as rnn input, see [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn). However, you'll need to write your own cell Class for processing this specific type of input. In this case, it should be something like:

```
# Define your own cell which accept (integer, bool) input
class YourCell(tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell):
    # override relevant functions of base interface: RNNCell
    # state_size, output_size, etc.

    # The main body of computation logic goes in this function
    def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
        # note inputs variable contains inputs of only one time step
        # for example, inputs = (5, True)
        interger, boolean = inputs
        # your computation

integer_input = [5, 2, 3, 4]
bool_input = [True, False, False, True]
inputs = [integer_input, bool_input]
cell = YourCell()
outputs = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(inputs, cell)
```